# Unable to listen for event on received DASH transaction using MeteorJS and DASH npm package

Tags: meteor

I am using the DASH npm package with a MeteorJS application. I would like to be able to listen for transaction events so I can call a Meteor method called "funds" whenever a transaction is sent to my wallet. However, I am receiving "undefined" errors in the console when attempting to set this up.

Documentation:
https://dashevo.github.io/platform/SDK/examples/receive-money-and-check-balance/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dash

What I would like to do looks in theory like this (fixtures.js):

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {

  const Dash = require("dash");
  const mnemonic = 'there ghost stay ripple silk gym curtain body salad icon sentence service';
  const client = new Dash.Client({ network: "testnet", wallet: { mnemonic } });
  client.getWalletAccount().then(async (account) => {
    account.events.on('FETCHED_CONFIRMED_TRANSACTION', (data)=>{ 
      var amount = data.amount;
      var address = data.address;
      if (address) {
          Meteor.call('funds', address, amount, (error) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
              }
          });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is what I have and what has worked successfully:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {

  const Dash = require("dash");
  const mnemonic = 'there ghost stay ripple silk gym curtain body salad icon sentence service';
  const client = new Dash.Client({ network: "testnet", wallet: { mnemonic } });
  client.getWalletAccount().then(async (account) => {
    console.log("Funding address", account.getUnusedAddress().address); // THIS WORKS!!!
    console.log("Confirmed Balance", account.getConfirmedBalance()); // THIS WORKS!!!
    // THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT CURRENTLY WORK!!!
    // account.events.on('FETCHED_CONFIRMED_TRANSACTION', (data)=>{
    //   console.log('FETCHED/UNCONFIRMED_TRANSACTION');
    //   console.dir(data);
    //   var amount = data.amount;
    //   var address = data.address;
    //   if (address) {
    //       Meteor.call('funds', address, amount, (error) => {
    //           if (error) {
    //               console.log(error);
    //           }
    //       });
    //   }
    // });
  });
  
});
```

I have also tried the following per the documentation to no avail:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {

  const Dash = require("dash");
  const mnemonic = 'there ghost stay ripple silk gym curtain body salad icon sentence service';
  const client = new Dash.Client({ network: "testnet", wallet: { mnemonic } });
  client.account.events.on('FETCHED/UNCONFIRMED_TRANSACTION', (data)=>{
    console.log('FETCHED/UNCONFIRMED_TRANSACTION');
    console.dir(data)
  });

});
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation is currently in the process of updating

Instead of account.events.on do account.on
https://github.com/dashevo/platform/issues/377#issuecomment-1124617321